# array variable might not have been initialized error

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, syntax-error

I created class Supervisor which contains the constructor and a toString method. However when I try to print an Index of the array an error occur,"Variable svArray might not have been initialized.
What can I do to solve this ?

```
Supervisor[] svArray;
if (mainChoice == 3){
        String ID, name, department, resarch;
        System.out.println("Enter How Many Supervisor you want to enter : ");
        svNumber = input.nextInt();
        svArray = new Supervisor[svNumber];
        for (int i = 0; i < svNumber; i++) {
            System.out.println("---Enter Supervisor " + (i + 1) + " Of " + svNumber + " ---");
            System.out.println("Enter staff ID : ");
            ID = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter name : ");
            name = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter department : ");
            department = input.next();
            svArray[i]=new Supervisor(ID, name, department);\
        }


    }
System.out.print(svArray[1].toString)
//Error, variable svArray might not have been initialized
```

Comment: You can't use a un-initialized variable in java. what about if mainChoice is not equal to 3.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that on this line:

```
System.out.print(svArray[1].toString)
```

`svArray` hasn't been initialized in case that `mainChoice != 3`, because you initialize the array inside of `if` statement which is not executed.

To overcome this problem you can initialize the array to `null`:

```
Supervisor[] svArray = null;
```

And then check for `null`:

```
if(svArray != null) System.out.print(svArray[1].toString());
```

Comment: This doesn't compile because arrays don't have a `toString` attribute (admittedly the error is present in the OP's code as well).

Comment: @JonK but you call `toString` on first element of said array which is `Supervisor` type

Comment: But you aren't calling `toString()`. That's my point. Method calls have brackets.

Comment: @JonK Oh I see, thanks! I didn't noticed that and just blindly copy&pasted.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put you initialize the array inside the if statement but use it outside. So if the content of the if statement never runs (that is whenever mainChoice is not 3) the array is used at the end without being initialized.

Answer (score 1):

If `mainChoice` is not equal to 3, svArray never gets initialized. You need to either place the print statement into the `if` block or unconditionally initialize svArray[1] to some value.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables differ from member variables in that they **don't** get automatically initialised to a default value for you. Java doesn't allow you to use a variable that hasn't been initialised yet, and the JVM can't know if `mainChoice` is always going to be `3`. Because of this, the compiler can't be certain that your array will have been initialised by the time the call to `System.out.print(svArray[1].toString)` is attempted - hence your error.

It's not clear why you're declaring `svArray` outside of your loop, so this code may not be entirely appropriate:

```
if (mainChoice == 3){
    String ID, name, department, resarch;
    System.out.println("Enter How Many Supervisor you want to enter : ");
    svNumber = input.nextInt();
    Supervisor[] svArray = new Supervisor[svNumber];
    for (int i = 0; i < svNumber; i++) {
        System.out.println("---Enter Supervisor " + (i + 1) + " Of " 
            + svNumber + " ---");
        System.out.println("Enter staff ID : ");
        ID = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter name : ");
        name = input.next();
        System.out.println("Enter department : ");
        department = input.next();
        svArray[i]=new Supervisor(ID, name, department);\
    }
    System.out.print(svArray[1].toString())
}
```

There are three important changes to note here.

- The declaration and initialisation of `svArray` now occur on the same line within your `if` statement.
- The `System.out.println` call now also happens inside your `if` statement so that `svArray` is still in scope.
- It now correctly invokes the `toString()` *method*, rather than attempting to access an attribute called `toString` (which doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

```
 svArray[i]=new Supervisor(ID, name, department);
```

You initialized the above array inside the if statement. So when you're saying:`System.out.print(svArray[1].toString)`Java does not know that you initialized it inside the if statement. anything inside a block{} has a scope that is only valid inside that specific block segment, if that block is not the class type. Suppose you define something out of the class block then you will not get your variable or declaration working within the class block. However, if you use ArrayList then you may not need to initialize the size of it so just simply declaring the ArrayList in the class block will let you use it/initialize it in other methods/ statements.